# javascript dynamically creating an object with random numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I have an Object which is empty at the beginning,

```js
var theList = {}
```

I need to populate it with random key value pairs and the final structure of the object should be like this:

```js
theList{
  id1{
    fname: "some Name"
    lname: "some Last Name"
  }
  id2{
    fname: "some OTHER Name"
    lname: "some OTHER Last Name"
   }
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

**NOTE: ** the number "1" and "2" of id1 and id2 must be generated dynamically

Comment: This is a question and answer site, not a code writing service. „I need“ is not a question, so this post is off topic.

Comment: If you have tried something that isn't working, please include that here.  Otherwise this is nothing more than homework we're doing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over a set of number and create the object key by appending `id` with the number

```js
let theList = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  theList['id' + i] = {
    fname: "some Name",
    lname: "some Last Name"
  }


}

console.log(theList)
```

Comment: Can I access it the same way on android?

Answer (score 0):

In these cases I usually use this nom package: https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/